# Local networking using URLSession - Swift 4.2, Xcode 10.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, networking, local

I am trying to make an HTTP request over the local network to an IP address. However, when I call dataTask it doesn't actually make the request. Requests to the internet work fine. I also tried making the request from HTTPBot and it was successful.

Here's the code that's making the call:

```
    let url = apiBaseUrl + "get_serial"
    let urlObj = URL(string: url)
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: urlObj!)

    urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
    urlRequest.cachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else { return }

            let serial = (String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))

            onSuccess(serial ?? "")
        }
```

The url is correctly defined as `http://192.168.0.50/get_serial`

I tried to step through it, but after it hits URLSession.shared.dataTask it doesn't do anything else. I suspected a threading issue and tried adding a delay, as well as trying to dispatch the dataTask from the global thread, but neither worked. I also tried to allow arbitrary loads in my .plist file and add that IP as an exception domain: [image: plist]

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1410330-datatask):

> After you create the task, you must start it by calling its [resume()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontask/1411121-resume) method.

So you have to hold onto the `URLSession.shared.dataTask` instance and start it with the `resume` method. Something like the following.

```
let url = apiBaseUrl + "get_serial"
let urlObj = URL(string: url)
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: urlObj!)

urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
urlRequest.cachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlObj!) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        let serial = (String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))

        onSuccess(serial ?? "")
    }

task.resume()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I added .resume() and it worked. I knew I forgot something trivial. Time for a break :)